Use Azure Data Factory To Query Data in Salesforce
I'm using Azure Data Factory to pull data into a SQL database to simplify some ETL operations. Previously I have used DBAmp but the new company already had Data Factory setup and prefers it for security and risk management reasons.
When using Azure Data Factory, I set up a Linked Service and a Parameterized data source. This works great with the Copy Data Pipeline Element by default this copies the entire table (all rows and columns) and doesn't allow for querying related tables. This is way too much data for some operations I want to do and doesn't work on certain objects like Content Document Link or Activity Metric which require specific conditions when querying.
For this, I want to use a SOQL query.
This works fine for queries with either no filters or simple filters. An example of a query that does not work:
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE SomeRelationship.SomeField__c != null OR SomeRelationship.SomeField__c != null

This results in an error:
MALFORMED_QUERY: \nSomeRelationship.SomeField__c != null and Id >= '003000000000000' and\n  ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:272\nunexpected token: and"},Source=Microsoft.Connectors.Salesforce,'

You'll notice that AZDF is automatically adding filters to the query and these filters are breaking the query.

After some trial and error, I've determined that adding Parenthesis around the 2 filters resolves the issue:
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE SomeRelationship.SomeField__c != null OR SomeRelationship.SomeField__c != null

turns into:
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE (SomeRelationship.SomeField__c != null OR SomeRelationship.SomeField__c != null)

This prevents the engine from adding erroneous filters and breaking the query. I was not able to find any documentation to indicate why the filters were being added or why parenthesis seems to resolve the issue.
Additionally,
It also appears that when AZDF creates a new table based on the query the "." is not removed from the field name which breaks SSMS as it expects the "." to represent a multi-part identifier. The column may need to be renamed after the table is created into SQL for it to function properly. (DBAmp automatically swaps "." to "_").
